# Get single number from web API, instead of dictionary

Tags: python, json, rest

Having problem with my Python quiz game and I dont really know how to move forward with it. The questions come from an API and I want to be able to answer with a number what the right question is(I have fixed so that the questions alternative have number infront of them). I can write the right answer right now but not with a number. When I write the wrong answer or answer with a number I get the whole dictionary back like this:

```
Wrong, right answer is: [{'answer': 'print', 'correct': True}, {'answer': 'input', 'correct': False}, {'answer': 'import', 'correct': False}, {'answer': 'sys.exit', 'correct': False}]
```

I just want the right answer back, but I dont really know how to fix that.
So, I want to be able to answer with an number and just get the right answer back. How do I fix this? I have tried to apply int(user_answer) - 1 in the main function at the correct_answer = question['answers'], but I dont get it to work so maybe its the wrong approach.

```
import requests

url = ""
the_questions = requests.get(url).json()

print("------ Welcome to Python Quiz ------")


def compare_answer(correct, answers):
    return any(ca["correct"] and ca["answer"].strip().lower() == answers for ca in correct)


def get_correct_answers(answers):
    res = []
    for ans in answers:
        if ans['correct']:
            res.append(ans['answer'])
    return res


def main():
    score = 0
    for question in the_questions['questions']:
        print(question['prompt'])

        for i, a in enumerate(question['answers'], start=1):
            print(f"[{i}] {a['answer']}")

        user_answer = input("> ")
        correct_answer = question['answers']
        if compare_answer(correct_answer, user_answer):
            score += 1
            print(f"Right!")
        else:
            print(f"Wrong, the right answer is: {correct_answer}")
    print(f"You got {score} points out of 3!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is how to API looks right now, if it helps with something.

```
{"questions":[{"id":"1","prompt":"Vilken funktion anv\u00e4nder du f\u00f6r att skriva ut text i terminalen?","answers":[{"answer":"print","correct":true},{"answer":"input","correct":false},{"answer":"import","correct":false},{"answer":"sys.exit","correct":false}]},{"id":"2","prompt":"Hur tar man fram l\u00e4ngden p\u00e5 listan i variabeln \"fruits\"?","answers":[{"answer":"for _ in range(10)","correct":false},{"answer":"input(fruits)","correct":false},{"answer":"len(fruits)","correct":true}]},{"id":"3","prompt":"Vad heter nyckelordet f\u00f6r att g\u00f6ra en loop i python?","answers":[{"answer":"in","correct":false},{"answer":"for","correct":true},{"answer":"while","correct":true}]}]}
```

Comment: so, why are you not making use of your own function `get_correct_answers()`?

Comment: @Neuron I got help writing it, but I dont really know how to use it correctly

Comment: To me it seems you are lacking the fundamentals of dictionaries/collections. This is normal for a programming beginner, but you should be honest with yourself, someone showing you the solution will help you very little in understanding it better. find a good tutorial online (youtube has a bunch of python tutorials) and try to understand it well enough to solve the problem on your own :)

Answer (score 0):

The `get_correct_answers()` function will return the correct answers. So call that and show its result.

```
        if compare_answer(correct_answer, user_answer):
            score += 1
            print(f"Right!")
        else:
            all_correct = ", ".join(get_correct_answers(correct_answer)
            print(f"Wrong, the right answer is: {all_correct}")
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it looks way better. I tried to add int(user_answer) - 1 to the code one row up to be able to answer with numbers, but I just get an KeyError.

Comment: It looks like the user enters the text of the answer, not the number. Your `compare_answer()` function doesn't look for a number.